# Error when preparing query - MySQLIi class "SHOW TABLES LIKE" error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using this database class for my project: [GitHub](https://github.com/avbdr/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php).

When trying to execute a SHOW query to determine whether a table exists or not I receive this error:

> Fatal error: Problem preparing query (SHOW TABLES LIKE users) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'users' at line 1 in mysqli.php on line 679

The query looks like this:

```
$result = $DATABASE->rawQuery("SHOW TABLES LIKE " . $TABLE);
```

`$TABLE` is obviously filled with a string, I double checked that.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($TABLE)` — What does it output?

Comment: What do you expect `SHOW TABLES LIKE users` to output? I think you need something along the lines of `SHOW TABLES LIKE %users%` instead (`%` is a wildcard)

Comment: It's supposed to show every table matching that, and the % don't help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed the quotes:

```
$result = $DATABASE->rawQuery("SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $TABLE . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The like statement it's value is wrong.

You should use:

BAD

```
$result = $DATABASE->rawQuery("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'value here' ");
```

Good

```
$result = $DATABASE->rawQuery("SHOW TABLES LIKE ? ");
$DATABASE->addParam($table);
```

I think you allso want to add % in front and after your $table :)

Comment: have you tried the param method?
It could be that users is a reserved word maybe try %use%
If you dont use params be sure to ad quotes around it

Comment: I did try it, it didn't change anything.